# Рекурсивный реверс строки с добавление в StringBuilder

Tags: java, рекурсия

Понимаю как работает мой метод "Рекурсивный реверс строки", но не понимаю почему когда я вместо этой строки `stringBuilder.append(reMethod(str.substring(0, str.length()-1)));` напишу `reMethod(str.substring(0, str.length()-1));`, StringBuilder перестает добавлять строки из предыдущего метода в мой StringBuilder, объясните, пожалуйста, как срабатывает StringBuilder или String в рекурсивный методах?

```
private String reMethod(String str){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if(str.length() == 1){
        stringBuilder.append(str);
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    stringBuilder.append(reMethod(str.substring(0, str.length()-1)));
    stringBuilder.insert(0,str.charAt(str.length()-1));
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно проблема в том, что на каждый вызов метода у вас создается новый StringBuilder, попробуйте создавать StringBuilder вне метода и
передавать его в качестве параметра, например

```
private String reMethod(String str, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    if(str.length() == 1){
        stringBuilder.append(str);
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    reMethod(str.substring(0, str.length()-1), stringBuilder);
    stringBuilder.insert(0,str.charAt(str.length()-1));
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```